# Simulating multiple user input junit

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a junit test to test a method that takes multiple user input.
The method takes a person object and sets a rating for them, the first user input is a double value for the rating, the second input is a string with the value "Y" to confirm the change.

I am trying to use ByteArrayInputStream but it is not getting the second input, the error I am getting when i run the test is No line found.

I have identified the problem as I am using different methods to validate user input I have to create a new scanner each time so the second line is not being accepted

Is there a way to set the Scanner again for the second input?

This is my test code

```
 Person p = new Person();

    double input1 = 54.3;
    String input2 = "Y";

    String simulatedUserInput = input1 + 
    System.getProperty("line.separator")
    + input2 + System.getProperty("line.separator");


    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(simulatedUserInput.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

    addRating(p);

    assertEquals(54.3, p.getMyRating(),0);
```

The method for adding the rating looks like this

```
    public static void addRating(Person p)
{

    double rating = Validation.validateRating("Please enter a rating for " + p.getName()); // validate input of double

    boolean confirmed = Validation.validateYesNo("Are you sure you wish to set " + p.getName() + "'s rating to " + rating + " Y/N");// confirm yes no

    if (confirmed) 
    {
        p.setMyRating(rating);
    }

}
```

Then I have a validation class to ensure correct user input,
 This is for the rating

```
    public static double validateRating(String str)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double d = 0;
    boolean valid = false;
    while (!valid)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
        if (!in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("Not a valid number");
            in.nextLine();
        } else
        {

            d = in.nextDouble();

            if(d>=0 && d<=100)
            {
               valid = true; 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Rating must be between 0 and 100");
            }

        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

this is for confirming Y/N input

```
    public static boolean validateYesNo(String str)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean YesNo = false;
    boolean valid = false;

    while (!valid)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
        String choice = in.next();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            valid = true;
            YesNo = true;
        } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            valid = true;
            YesNo = false;
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }
    return YesNo;
}
```

Comment: `System.setIn(` This seems ugly as hell for a unit test.  Restructure your code to take an input String as a paramter, and call that method from the unit test.  In live code, reading a string and passing it as a parameter is easy, so there's no need to actually test `System.in` any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get unit testing wrong. You don't write your production code first; to later discover: this is **really hard** to test.

Instead: right from the beginning, you strive to write code that is as easy as possible. Ideally, you even write testcases **before** you write production code.

Because that helps you discovering the abstractions you need. In your case: in order to validate *input* values within your Person class, it **should** not be important, where those values are coming from.

In other words: you do **not never ne jamais** put System.in read calls into your production classes. You might have a test `main` method that reads values from the console; but you always **pass** such values into a method as parameter. If at all, you pass an instance *Reader* into your classes. You do **not** turn to System.in inside your methods!